# Css the same text word wrapping when changing from plain to bold

Tags: html, css, text-formatting

I have seen several good answers how to avoid shifting right items when using bold for hover. My problem is different. I am having arbitrary text that has to fit in already fixed box size. We talking of a very short text, 2-3 words changing the width is not significant and it is ok.

The issue is when the wording is such that the wrapping in plain is one line and when bold it goes in two lines. For example

<kbd>This is example text</kbd>

<kbd>**This is example     
text**</kbd>

Is there a way to enforce the word wrapping for the bold version when actually writing the plain text. This way even when the text is plain it will be wrapped:

<kbd>This is example       
text</kbd>

...and this will make the transition smoother.

this demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bpxf4tq0/5/

```
<button class="launch">This is example text</button>

button.launch {
  border: none;
  width: 120px;
}

button.launch:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: you may use `&nbsp;` between words

Comment: @TemaniAfif sure, but I do want the text to get wrapped. I just want it to be wrapped in the same way

Comment: so can you share an example of code so we can better see

Comment: @TemaniAfif added to the question

Comment: If the text is arbitrary, there is no way to determine that the bold version would exceed width of the container using CSS. You would need to use javascript to determine either a word count, or bolded content width and then add a `<br>` tag or adjust container padding. In my opinion, bold is a poor choice to highlight hover anyway. I find the text width change jarring.

Comment: @JonP it is actually for selection. I thought it will be easier to explain the problem if I use hover. It does not seem to make difference for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with letter spacing. Of course the regular font will not look right this way, but depending on the application this might be acceptable.

```css
button.launch {
  border: none;
  width: 120px;
  letter-spacing: 0.033em;
}

button.launch:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.033em;
}
```

You can of course also keep the letter spacing of the regular font unchanged, and only narrow it for the bold font.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can't be done without JavaScript, but you can do the reverse: make the button's default width as wide as the width it will have when displayed in bold. One trick for this is to put the bold text in as well (invisibly), forcing the button to have the greater width.

One way of doing this is to put the text into an attribute and to display the contents of the attribute in the ::before pseudo-element.

In this example I have two buttons, one with the treatment (which always has the "bold" width) and for comparison, one behaving in the normal way (i.e. getting wider when bolded).

```css
button:hover {
  font-weight: bold
}

button::after {
  content: attr(data-value);
}

button.launch::before {
  content: attr(data-value);
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="launch" data-value="This is example text"></button>
<hr>
<button data-value="This is example text"></button>
```

Hope this helps as a workaround!